# How to Check the time a player is below a y-Coordinate in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, while-loop

I want my script to check how long the player is below a given y coordinate. However, since I am checking for the information inside a FixedUpdate void I cannot directly add a while loop. therefore, I tried the following:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
if(rb.position.y < 1f)
        {
            checkIfLost();
        }
}

IEnumerator checkIfLost()
    {
        while(rb.position.y < 1f)
        {
            float timeGiven = 5 - Time.deltaTime;

            if(timeGiven <= 0)
            {
                FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

This does not work. 
I am new to unity C#, and I have tried searching it online but could not find anything.

What is a better alternative for running the while loop and checking how long the player is below a y-coordinate?

Comment: Sounds like you got a colission box between Y and the bottom of the screen, then do a colission check.

Comment: Thats not how you start a coroutine, I would suggest looking into the documentation on it, also consider storing your GameManager instead of finding it every loop.  Is there a reason you need this in a FixedUpdate?  if you are just timing it Update should be fine, especially since fixedupdate can run multiple times a frame.  You can have all of the Updates; FixedUpdate, Update, LateUpdate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a float variable as counter

```
private float timer = 0f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
     if(rb.position.y < 1f)
     {
            timer +=Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            if (timer > 5f)
            {
                //do something
                FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
            }
     }
     else
     {
          timer = 0f;
     }
}
```

if you want to do that in Update (better) just replace `timer +=Time.DeltaTime;`

Comment: My biggest concern with this is fixed update can run multiple times per frame, so I am curious as to why they need it in fixedupdate...

Comment: learn from our errors.... just few persons read book or see tutorial video

Comment: Not sure why your answer got downvoted, but it does answer the question.

Comment: Wow, I am so sorry I wasted your time on this. It was so simple yet I could not think of it. Thank so much!! It has been a long day I guess. I have also moved it to Update() instead of FixedUpdate().

Comment: if you are happy, you dont waste my time...! welcome...last day of lockdown, dont forget to upvote too..